# How to to sort groups by their count in GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

While using `DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl` I am trying do the following, When a column is selected and dragged to the upper part of grid (i.e grouping by that column) I want the groups to be sorted by their member count. I have found no source about how to even begin doing that. I am not sure if it is even possible.

What I am getting: (Name of Column is Message)

```
Message:(Count=2) X

Message:(Count=7) U

Message:(Count=5) Z
```

What I want:

```
Message:(Count=7) U

Message:(Count=5) Z

Message:(Count=2) X
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the `StartGrouping` event of the grid (more info [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_StartGroupingtopic)). Then I think that it is a matter of sorting the grouped rows manually by setting their indexes giving a row's count.